# Match <=, ==, >= and != using regex

Tags: regex

What regex can I use to match the following

<=, >=, ==, !=

in "var1 <= var2"

I tried using (?<=(<(?==))) but doesn't work

Comment: Can you not just use a character set: `[<>=!]=` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Better put that in as an answer before someone usurps it :)

Comment: @RGraham Yeah, too late now lol - nvm

Comment: `(?<=(<(?==)))` doesn't look anyhow like what you wanted. Could you please elaborate how it was supposed to work, so that we can explain your mistakes and you can learn from it?

Comment: Wow, talk about a misleading title.

Answer (score 3):

Try this expression:

```
([<>!=]=)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
[<>=!]=
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the simple `(<=|>=|==|!=)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an or comparison:

```
(<=|>=|==|!=)
```